# MessageDialog missing in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, assembly-references, messagedialog

I am new in WPF C#.

I want to use a MessageDialog, but I can't instantiate it because I can't find its namespace reference.

Please note that I can use a MessageBox.

I take a screenshot here:

[image]

What should I look to solve the problem?

---

> **Update**
> I tried to use a ModalWindow as suggested by some user who deleted his answer, but I have the same problem.

[image]

Comment: WPF and WinForms are different, you shouldn't be using stuff from the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace (and not even reference the library). WPF has its own MessageBox

Comment: Also, not sure what `MessageDialog` is supposed to be, but [it's not part of the .NET Framework](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=messagedialog). Do you mean the UWP [`MessageDialog` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog)?

Comment: I see it from [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-show-message-dialog-35468701).

Comment: As was said in another palce, MessageDialog is from UWP. Wich while Similar to WPF, has a totally different target Framework. The closest equivalent to the WindowsForms MessageBox in WPF is MessageBox (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602949.aspx)

Comment: Why not just use System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("..."); ?

Comment: For the while I'm using MessageBox.Show("...", "...");. But I want something more beautiful.

Comment: `System.Windows.MessageBox` is a call to the windows default message box however UWP is designed to run with out knowing what operating systems they are running on ie Windows, windowsPhone, XBox so they had to include a new multi platform message box this is the `MessageDialog` hence its only available on UWP

Comment: you can build your own message window by calling the window with the `Window.ShowDialog()` but you will have to design it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MessageDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog) is a UWP class, so it is only available to Windows 10 Store applications. As far as I know it does not exist in WPF.
The namespace is `Windows.UI.Popups`.

Comment: You are correct, it's not part of WPF, it's only available to UWP apps. Not sure why the OP is looking for that in WinForms

Comment: OK thanks. It was what I needed to understand. However, there was no need to downvote the question, I worked to try to be clear and understandable.

Comment: @kitsune: Nobody had any idea what "MessageBox" even is. Nor why you looked for it in the Windows.Forms Namespace.

Comment: @kitsune: You had a book-example of a XY Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) You had a problem X (Designs were not respected). Convinced yourself Y (MessageDialog) was the only solution. And thus never explained X

Comment: If Windows.IU.Popups namespace is only there for UWP, how do I use something like this in WPF?